# Installing XP on Skylake machine: Installation media fails to boot with error "ntdetect failed"

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I am trying to install Windows XP on a Z170 machine with a Skylake processor. Although I am aware that Microsoft has discontinued support for XP, I want to install it on a secondary hard drive for compatibility with some old video games. I cannot use a Virtual Machine for a variety of reasons.

After using nLite to slipstream in some AHCI drivers, I burned the image to an installation CD using the built-in functionality in Windows 10. I then connected a PS/2 mouse and keyboard to prevent any possible issues with USB compatibility under the Skylake chipset. Almost immediately after rebooting into my installation CD, however, my computer crashes with the message "NTDetect Failed."

Google tells me that this error is generally related to corrupted system files. However, the same iso file I used to burn my CD boots correctly inside of Virtualbox. Burning a new CD didn't change anything, either.

I'm not sure what else to try at this point. Does anyone know what's going on? Is there anything else I can do, or is it simply not possible to install XP on a Skylake machine?

Edit: Just to reiterate, **the problem is not related to USB!** I am using optical media + a PS/2 mouse and keyboard in order to avoid any possible issues with USB compatibility.

Comment: Z170 chipset may not be  natively supporting Windows XP. Have you also checked the motherboard / chipset manual for OS support?

Comment: Chipset manual? My motherboard manual doesn't mention Windows XP at all.

Comment: Intel stopped supporting booting to USB 2.0 devices.  Windows XP has no support for USB 3.0 devices. This is entirely separate from USB compatibility mode by the way

Comment: I know--that's why I'm not using USB at all (except for one test). I'm using a PS/2 mouse and keyboard, and booting from a physical CD.

Comment: See this...http://forum.hwbot.org/showthread.php?t=142991

Comment: @Moab, thanks for the help, but see above: I'm not using USB at all. I'll add a bolded line to the original question so this is more clear.

Comment: @Moab (just saw your second comment) Thanks, so it definitely looks like it's possible to get XP working with Skylake! It doesn't seem to help me directly, though, since all the fixes seem to be USB-related. :(